# "Like Us" functionality of Facebook using Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-like

I need to Like a particular page of Facebook through my Application.

Below is my code

```
 @IBAction func btnLikeUsClicked(sender: AnyObject) {


        let urlStr = "MY_PAGE_URL"
        var modifiedURLString = String (format: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?object=%@&access_token=%@", urlStr,FBSession.activeSession().accessTokenData.accessToken)

        println("Modified String : \(modifiedURLString)")

        var facebookUrl = NSURL(string: modifiedURLString)
        var req = NSMutableURLRequest (URL: facebookUrl!)
        req.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var response : AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer <NSURLResponse?> = nil
        var err : NSErrorPointer = nil
        var resData : NSData  = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(req, returningResponse: response,  error: err)!
        var Content = NSString(data: resData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    }
```

But I am not getting any effect.

Please help me further

Comment: What is the result in `resData` after you sent the request? Is the app actually allowed to use the internet connection?

Comment: For what I remeber you can't like pages from app, just object, such as pictures, posts

Comment: @SebastianDressler resData gives me some bytes of data

Comment: @Andrea Can you please tell how can I do this "Like us" for Object like picture and Photo.

Comment: Have you tried using the FB sdk instead of creating the URL by yourself

Comment: @Andrea I am not finding any way to do.. Please Suggest

Comment: @Myaaoonn and what does the data mean?

Comment: You cannot like Pages via the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot og.like a page. If you want that, use the Like button for iOS: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button